# program to Unit Test in Visual Studio 2008 VC++ (.exe file)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, testing, visual-c++

What program is best to unit test a exe targeted project in Visual Studio 2008, VC++?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using Boost::Test and just creating a separate project. Answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249264/visual-studio-and-boosttest) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I used a cmake for managing my project and its unit tests. By cmake I generated visual studio files, then in visual studio I had project 'RUN_TESTS'. When I rebuilt it the tests were invoked.

Here You have some info:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Testing_With_CTest